# SqsListener method is acting strangely and doesn't seem to poll all messages?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, amazon-sqs

I have set up Spring Boot with Amazon SQS. My listener method is just printing out the received messages and I'm running a test server. I have a sender method that sends a message every 30 seconds but my received only shows (in the log) receives one message every approximately 5 or 6 minutes which I can't find anywhere I have configured that and it only receives the last one that is being sent not all the others in between.

Looking at the monitoring tab in AWS console I can't really tell if my listener is consuming them or not. It's my first time using Amazon SQS and I'm not sure if something I am missing in my configuration.

This is some of my configurations:

```
    @Bean
    fun simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(amazonSqs: AmazonSQSAsync?): SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory? {
        val factory = SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory()
        factory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSqs)
        factory.setAutoStartup(true)
        factory.setMaxNumberOfMessages(5)
        //factory.setVisibilityTimeout(10)
        factory.setWaitTimeOut(15)
        // ...
        return factory
    }

    @Bean
    fun queueMessageHandlerFactory(): QueueMessageHandlerFactory? {
        val factory = QueueMessageHandlerFactory()
        val messageConverter = MappingJackson2MessageConverter()
        messageConverter.isStrictContentTypeMatch = false
        factory.setArgumentResolvers(mutableListOf<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver>(PayloadMethodArgumentResolver(messageConverter)))
        return factory
    }
```

and here is my sender/listener service:

```
@Service
class MyMessageService(
    private val queueMessagingTemplate: QueueMessagingTemplate
){



    fun send(message: String) {

        val headers: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
        headers["message-group-id"] = "messageGroupId-${(1..1000).random()}"
        headers["message-deduplication-id"] = "messageDeduplicationId"
        logger.info { "===> Sending $message" }
        queueMessagingTemplate.send("MyTestQueue.fifo",
            MessageBuilder.createMessage(message, SqsMessageHeaders(headers)))
    }

    @SqsListener("MyTestQueue.fifo", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
    fun receive(message: String) {
        logger.info { "<=== Received $message" }
    }
}
```

And this is the log, as you can see the listener doesn't seem to receive everything:

```
2022-11-18 12:17:00.009  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 226 }
2022-11-18 12:17:30.004  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 23 }
2022-11-18 12:18:00.005  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 488 }
2022-11-18 12:18:00.082  INFO 75159 --- [enerContainer-2]      : <=== Received { "test": 488 }
2022-11-18 12:18:30.003  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 240 }
2022-11-18 12:19:00.004  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 797 }
2022-11-18 12:19:30.005  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 501 }
2022-11-18 12:20:00.004  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 978 }
2022-11-18 12:20:30.003  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 583 }
2022-11-18 12:21:00.001  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 124 }
2022-11-18 12:21:30.005  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 218 }
2022-11-18 12:22:00.002  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 617 }
2022-11-18 12:22:30.004  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 581 }
2022-11-18 12:23:00.004  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 984 }
2022-11-18 12:23:30.010  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 827 }
2022-11-18 12:23:30.070  INFO 75159 --- [enerContainer-2]      : <=== Received { "test": 827 }
2022-11-18 12:24:00.010  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 363 }
2022-11-18 12:24:30.003  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 990 }
2022-11-18 12:25:00.006  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 844 }
2022-11-18 12:25:30.005  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 650 }
2022-11-18 12:26:00.004  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 420 }
2022-11-18 12:26:30.006  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 719 }
2022-11-18 12:27:00.009  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 873 }
2022-11-18 12:27:30.004  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 521 }
2022-11-18 12:28:00.006  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 911 }
2022-11-18 12:28:30.010  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 267 }
2022-11-18 12:29:00.002  INFO 75159 --- [   scheduling-1]      : ===> Sending { "test": 164 }
2022-11-18 12:29:00.058  INFO 75159 --- [enerContainer-2]      : <=== Received { "test": 164 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to answer my own question because this can also happen to others. So basically the issue was this line:

`headers["message-deduplication-id"] = "messageDeduplicationId"`

It's been hardcoded to a fixed value which as explained here:

> The message deduplication ID is the token used for deduplication of sent messages. If a message with a particular message deduplication ID is sent successfully, any messages sent with the same message deduplication ID are accepted successfully but aren't delivered during the 5-minute deduplication interval.

Link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagededuplicationid-property.html

The above, explains why it takes about 5 minutes for the receiver to poll new messages because the messages sent takes about 5 minutes to be pushed.

I just changed that code to this and it works like a charm:

`headers["message-deduplication-id"] = "messageDeduplicationId-${(1..100).random()}"`